# Probability of an unlikely event repeated many times

Tags: probability

The probability of an event is 1/n. What is the probability of the event happening at least once if it is repeated n times. What is the limit of this probability as n goes to infinity?

Comment: Hello.  What are your thoughts on the question at hand?  Do you know how to use the complement of an event?

Answer (score 1):

The probability this event doesn't happen is $1-\frac{1}{n}$. Hence the probability that it never happens is $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$. Can you handle from here?

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of an event $E$ is $\frac{1}{n}$, then the complement of that event, $E^C$ would be $1-\frac{1}{n}$ If that is repeated $n$ times, then the probability of that event occuring is 
$$P(E^C \text{ n times }) = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$
Now take the limit...